# Object has no attribute 'get_absolute_url'

Tags: python, django

Hi I am creating a sitemap, it works fine on my local machine, but it gives the error **object has no attribute 'get_absolute_url'** in production server. I have a class

```
class Car(models.Model):
    slug=models.SlugField(unique=True)

    def save(self,*args,**kwargs):
        self.slug=slugify(self.brand+"-"+self.stelNum)
        super(Car,self).save(*args, **kwargs)

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return "/biler/"+str(self.slug)
```

and a sitemap class

```
class CarSitemap(Sitemap):
    changefreq = 'monthly'
    priority = 0.5

    def items(self):
        return Car.objects.all()
```

I have `get_absolute_url` function in my `Car` class, but why django is keeping telling me that **'Car' object has no attribute 'get_absolute_url'**
I use Django 1.6.5 and Python 2.7.8

Comment: Did you restart the wsgi process(es) on the production server ? Else you're still running on the old code...

Comment: Yes I have restart it many times

Comment: @martijn-pieters : the op _does_ have a `get_absolute_url` method in his class so it's not a duplicate of 14092601

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers: ah, in which case `Car` is not the same class, because otherwise they'd not get that exception. Still, reopened.

Comment: @MartijnPieters : yes I suppose it might be something like this (since it seems not to be a stale module issue).

Comment: @hln: You may have some obsolete `.pyc` file lying around, so first remove all `.pyc` files from your server install (and restart the server once again). If it doesn't cure the problem, add some trace to your code to print out which  `Car` class (and from which exact module) you're using on production (there's a whole chapter on logging in django's doc).

Comment: Once you clear the pyc, open a shell in django and import a car object. See if you indeed get the same error. If the error persists, edit the question with the exact stack trace

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers - great, thanks! I found that my server's \_\_pycache__ had old .pyc's as a result of changing python versions - removing them fixed the issue

Answer (score 0):

I found out bad indentation has causes the Error... I have develop my application in Eclipse, there doesn't matter it is a tab or a space. But in the development server, I have to pay attention to it.